# converting all files in a directory in unix to another format

Tags: unix, for-loop, sed, awk, directory

I have a list of files in a unix directory. All of them are called something.bed and I am looking to convert them all to something.txt

The .bed format can easily be read by txt editors but is not recognised as a txt file in coding languages such as python so doesn't seem to be read by standard txt parsing scripts.

This is probably quite an easy question for anyone with intermediate unix experience but I don't use unix much and have looked around and can't find a quick answer

I tried:

```
 for i in *.bed
 do cat > *.txt
 done
```

it just gives 1 file called *.txt, where I'm looking for 1.bed to become 1.txt and 2.bed to become 2.txt etc

Any pointers or solutions would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the variable properly in the `for` loop:

```
for i in *.bed
do
   cat $i > ${i%.*}.txt
done
```

While it would be better to use `mv` for this:

```
for i in *.bed
do
   mv $i ${i%.*}.txt
done
```

`${i%.*}.txt` converts `i.bed` into `i.txt.`

---

Why didn't your attempt work?

```
for i in *.bed
do
  cat > *.txt
done
```

As you are inside a `for` loop, the variable to use is `i`, not `*`. That is, when looping through the `*.bed` files, it is `i` variable that stores the values. Hence you need to use `i` to refer them.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in *.bed; do mv $i ${i/bed/txt}; done
```

Actually, the following would be safer since my first attempt would convert "bed.bed" into "txt.bed".

```
for i in *.bed; do mv $i ${i/bed$/txt}; done
```

Comment: perfect, thank you very much - saved me loads of time!